# How to obtain bitrate, sample rate and bits per sample in python-vlc

Tags: libvlc, python-vlc

I am trying to obtain bitrate, sample rate actual bits per sample of an audio file using python-vlc.

I saw that we can use `libvlc_media_tracks_get()` to [obtain bitrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498697/how-to-retrieve-codec-information-using-libvlc), but I am not sure how to get the others.

But even if this method can obtain all 3 info, I still can't manage to make the method work. It takes 2 arguments `p_md` and `tracks`. I don't understand what is `tracks`. It says it requires an instance of `LP_LP_MediaTrack` but I can't somehow find what that means.

Comment: Have you parsed or played the media first?

Comment: Yes, I have done it

Comment: If you solved this problem on your own, then either wait a day and post a real answer if you think others will benefit from knowing how to do this, or delete the question if you think they'll be able to find the exact same information you did. Don't edit an answer into a question, that's not how SO works.

Comment: No, I haven't found my answer yet. Just because I figured out how to get bitrate doesn't mean I got the others.

Comment: Can you explain how can i print bitrate value with python-vlc module?

Comment: bits_per_sample = audio_total_size_in_bits/(total_duration_in_seconds*sample_rate_hz)

Comment: @ChrisP I have modified the question and posted an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitrate:

```py
# This allocates a double pointer and a MediaTrack object in RAM, then points to
# it, but no value is assigned to this double pointer or the MediaTrack object.
mediaTrack_pp = ctypes.POINTER(vlc.MediaTrack)()

# Assigns the MediaTrack in the double pointer to the values stored in `media`,
# returning the amount of media tracks as `n`
n = vlc.libvlc_media_tracks_get(media, ctypes.byref(mediaTrack_pp))

# Converts the double pointer to `POINTER` class that Python understands. We can
# then get the value the pointer is pointing at.
info = ctypes.cast(mediaTrack_pp, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(vlc.MediaTrack) * n))

# This gets the actual value of the double pointer i.e. value of MediaTrack
media_tracks = info.contents[0].contents
```

Sample rate (appending the above code):

```py
# According to the API doc, MediaTrack class has an `u` field which has an
# `audio` field, containing the audio track.
audio = ctypes.cast(media_tracks.u.audio, ctypes.POINTER(vlc.AudioTrack))

# The AudioTrack class has a `rate` field, which is the sample rate.
sample = audio.contents.rate
```

The main reason I couldn't get the bitrate is because I didn't understand how to get the data type `LP_LP_MediaTrack`. This is a double pointer of a MediaTrack instance.

When `vlc.libvlc_media_tracks_get(media, ctypes.byref(mediaTrack_pp))` runs, I think the library simply sets copies the MediaTrack instance in `media` to the actual memory location that`mediaTrack_pp` points to

We can then get the actual object in Python using the `ctypes.cast()` method. This algorithm should apply on all Python codes that uses `LP_xxx` data types, even for other libraries.

With that problem solved, all that left was to crunch the API documentation.
[VLC MediaTrack class documentation](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaTrack-class.html)

Comment: Bitrate information doesn't seem to be available in new versions of python-vlc (at the moment of writing this comment the newest version is 3.0.18121). The last version where bitrate information is available is 3.0.11115.